# Should I prefer functions compare to variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, constants

I saw in particular project this syntax used all the time:

```
function a() {
    return 'hello';
}
function b() {
    return `${a()} world`;
}
b();
```

and all variables were almost omitted. Why just don't use syntax below?

```
const a = `hello`;
const b = `${a} world`;
console.log(b);
```

What advantage has function used to return string compare to const, because I don't see any practical one. Only what comes to mine mind is that `const b` is executed all the time compare to `function b` which executed only when called. Am I missing something?

Comment: In what context was this used? I.e, was this in a class?

Comment: That is heavily dependant on how you are using the two functions. In the case of hardcoded strings (as in your example), there's no point to wrapping them in functions. However, if the result of `function a()` is dependant on other variables then it makes sense to put them in a function, as the value is only resolved once it is called.

Comment: The purpose was creating endpoint links in react and functions were then exported. f.e. to create link such is `/api/document`, `/api/file` etc.
I must admit, that this could be bad approach at all but have not found any answer for such practice.

Comment: @PavolTravnik Probably then because the endpoint library expects functions, and it doesn't know that they return constants. They could return new values on every call as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to provide API path the function approach provide more flexibility.

IE:

**You can switch environment (test/staging/prod) based on conditions (IE dotENV data). This is useful when managing base url of your API**

```
function getENV() {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'production': {
      return URL_PROD;
    }
    case 'staging': {
      return URL_STAGING;
    }
    case 'test': {
      return URL_TEST;
    }
    default: {
      return DEFAULT_URL;
    }
}
```

Another function can mix the default baseURL with your variable-stored endpoints

IE:

```
function getEndpointURL(endpoint) {
    return `${getENV()}/${endpoint}`
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this explanation is out of what I had at mind. I was wondering, why to use only simple function declaration without parameter and not to use a constant. It could be very small optimisation of resources and nothing all probably.

Comment: @PavolTravnik function call is always more expensive than variable lookup. So this will take more time instead. Only reason for such code is flexibility.

Comment: I assure you that when a big project comes, you'll want simple string in some cases (static endpoints path) and dynamic string (served by functions) in others (IE: http/https, baseurl, auth data etc etc). So you do not have to CHOOSE const approach or func approach, you'll end by using the mix of the two.

Comment: @Rajesh you are right, I've simplified a real snippet of my code, where other functions where called instead of returning a value

Comment: @Rajesh you are right again, function calls are more expensive and only advantage is flexibility. The flexibility gained anyway is much more than the performance you can lose.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini another optimization in such case would be having a hashMap of url. `const urlMap = {...}; const defaultUrl = '...'; getENV() { return urlMap[env] || defaultUrl; }`. Lookup is faster than conditional statements. ;-)  Have a good day.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I use a hasMaps too in my apps usually. Have a good day too, mate :)